# Hot Reload/Restart doesn't work in Flutter in Linux from TERMINAL only

Tags: linux, flutter, hot-reload, flutter-hotreload

When I run `flutter run` and press `r` or `R` hot reload/restart doesn't work and I have to press `r` or `R` every time I change my code.

I want to run my app only from the terminal and not from any IDE or Editor.

[HAVE TO PRESS `r` or `R` everytime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G69R1.png)

Comment: yes, if you run `flutter run ...` command you have to press `r` or `R` key every time you change your code

Comment: but then what's the point of "hot reload"?

Comment: the point is that it takes 500 ms or so and not couple of seconds